# How to call connection from a class in php OOPs using singleton class?

Tags: php

I am creating a project in PHP OOPs. I am using PHP version 8.2 and I have used composer to create the dependencies. But I am getting error as below. Can anyone help?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private Dbconnection::__construct() from global scope in D:\xampp\htdocs\studentdata.online\login.php:4 
Stack trace:
 #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\studentdata.online\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(53): require()
 #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\studentdata.online\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(36): composerRequire5c84f50f16f6cbc3b6f92f148353e368('61828216e682212...', 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
 #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\studentdata.online\vendor\autoload.php(12): ComposerAutoloaderInit5c84f50f16f6cbc3b6f92f148353e368::getLoader()
 #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\studentdata.online\login.php(2): require_once('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
 #4 {main} thrown in
```

### Dbconnection.php

```
<?php 
class Dbconnection
{
    private static $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance
    private $_host = "localhost";
    private $_username = "root";
    private $_password = "";
    private $_database = "xxxxx";

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, 
            $this->_password, $this->_database);
    
        // Error handling
        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            trigger_error("Failed to conencto to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(),
                 E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    public function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance=new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    private function __clone() { }
    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}
```

### login.php

```
<?php 
require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

$conn = new Dbconnection();
$db = $conn::getInstance();
$mysqli = $db->getConnection();
```

### composer.json

```
{
    "autoload":{
        "files":["login.php"],
        "classmap":["Dbconnection.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the constructor private? Why is the `getInstance()`  method not static, but called as such?

Comment: Also, why do you mix `new mysqli` (the OOP approach) and `mysqli_connect_error` (the function approach)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing a singleton, it's common to make the constructor and clone methods private. This will prevent anybody from doing `new DbConnection` and will force the use of `getInstance()`. However, in this case, any code inside the constructor will never run -- so you have to put your initialization inside a conditional in your `getInstance()`.

```
class DbConnection
{

    private static ?mysqli $db = null;

    // force singleton usage, disallow instantiation
    private function __construct() { }

    // force singleton usage, disallow cloning
    private function __clone() { }

    public static function getInstance(): mysqli
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            // do all your connection setup here
            self::$db = new mysqli(...);
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

}
```

Then usage is simply:

```
$db = DbConnection::getInstance();
```

So now you get:

```
// these two are the same object
$db1 = DbConnection::getInstance();
$db2 = DbConnection::getInstance();

// error
$db3 = new DbConnection();

// error
$db4 = clone $db1;
```